# Going out is more interesting than GOING / TO GO with your family

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, parallelism

I wonder which form suits this sentence:

> 1. Going out with your friends is more interesting than **to go** with your family!
> 2. Going out with your friends is more interesting than **going** with your family!

The reason is more important for me than answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think either one is “incorrect,” but I do think the second option reads better.

The reason? It’s a *parallel structure*. Had the sentence begun like this:

> To go out with your friends is...

then I would have voted for the first one.

The [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/1/) has a good example of parallel structures:

> **With the -ing form (gerund) of words:**
>
> - Parallel: Mary likes hiking, swimming, and bicycling.
>
> **With infinitive phrases:**
>
> - Parallel: Mary likes to hike, to swim, and to ride a bicycle.
> - OR: Mary likes to hike, swim, and ride a bicycle.

It goes on to recommend that forms should not be mixed:

> Mary likes hiking, swimming, and <strike>to ride</strike> a bicycle.